# How to get javascript new object information from javascript from webkit?

Tags: javascript, webkit, javascriptcore

I want to extract a new objects information name and arguments into a HTML page.
Such as

```
<script>
    var a = new g(10,20);
</script>
```

I need to print :

new object g with arguments 10,20

I am newbie to Webkit.
Initially I thought just add a printf statement in the javascriptcore. I added  some printf statements to 
JavaScriptCore/runtime/FunctionConstructor.cpp ,ObjectConstructor.cpp .

But didn't get right result .

I googled but there is few tutorials about javascriptcore. 
I hope some expert can point me in the right direction .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of WebKit are you hacking with, so my solution may not work.

I suggest you to add logging statements in Interpreter.cpp, inside the block of DEFINE_OPCODE(op_construct).